# Why does $c^Tx \le d$ on an affine set imply that $c^Tx = d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Why does $c^Tx \le d$ on an affine $D = \{x : Ax = b\}$ set imply that $c^Tx = d$?

I tried to proceed with a proof by contradiction assuming $c^Tx \not = d$ i.e. $c^Tx < d$. However, I don't see here any contradiction. Intuitively it is the intersection of a half-space with a hyperplane however, I am struggling to understand the problem.

Comment: This is not true: for instance, the affine set $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\,x_n=0\}$ is contained in the half space $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\, x_n\le 1\}$, but it is not contained in the hyperplane $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\, x_n=1\}$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks. Can you see my comment under the 5xum answer?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the thoroughly quantified final form of your statement would be upon adding the condition $x>0$.

Comment: You might be interested in noting that if any convex function is bounded from above, the function is a constant. A proof using the restriction property of the convex function is sufficient. This is however in the case that you mean that f is a distinct constant and not necessarily the d as defined.

Comment: @Harduin but the above statement is on affine set function and not convex function?

Answer (score 2):

It most certainly does not mean that. Take $c=\vec 0$ and $d=1$ for a counterexample.

Comment: What if we additionally know that $c \ge 0, d \le 0, x > 0$. Does that make any difference? Because the argument that is given in the text is: "Since $c^Tx \le d$ on $D$, which is an affine set, we must have $c^Tx$ constant
on $D$. (If $c^Tx$ weren’t constant on $D$, it would take on all values.)"

Comment: @user13 My counterexample satisfies all three conditions.

Comment: You have $d > 0$. If I take $d = -1$ then $c^Tx > d$ since both $c \ge 0$ and $x > 0$.

Comment: @daw The question was edited 19 months after it was posted, and not by the original author of the question. I couldn't be less interested if I tried.

Comment: yes, the edit was not justified. Rolled back the edit.