# Prove that there exists an x satisfying $x \geq 0, Ax =b$ iff there exists no $\lambda$ with $A^T\lambda \geq 0, A^T\lambda \neq 0, b^T\lambda \leq 0$

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Solution given is as follows

[image]

[image]

However, I cannot quite follow the argument in the last paragraph. There is even a post here [Why does $c^Tx \le d$ on an affine set imply that $c^Tx = d$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050024/why-does-ctx-le-d-on-an-affine-set-imply-that-ctx-d) that "disproves" the argument used.

Can someone explain the logic of this solution? If it is worng, how should we modify it?

Comment: Note in the linked question the claim was $c^Tx=d$ for all $x\in D$, which is false. Here the claim is: there is some $f$ such that $c^Tx=f$ for all $x\in D$, which is true. Note the other question had an edit that invalidated the comments/answer, I rolled back the edit to the original meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that there are $x_1 ,x_2\in D$ such that $c^T(x_1-x_2)\ne 0$.
Since $D$ is affine, we have $ x_1 + t(x_2-x_1)\in D$ for all $t$.
This implies
$$
c^T (x_1 + t(x_2-x_1) ) \le d\quad \forall t.
$$
Since $c^T(x_1-x_2) \ne0$, you can make the left-hand side arbitrarily large for $t\to \pm\infty$. Hence, we arrive at a contradiction.

This proves that $x\mapsto c^Tx$ is constant on $D$.